# Should there be a temporary table to hold Order and OrderItems?

Tags: database-design

After trying out a few open-source restaurant  POS, I still couldn't decide if there should be a temporary to hold Orders and OrderItems?

I was initially thinking to have temporary tables and permanent tables for Orders and OrderItems and move a record from temporary tables to permanent tables after an order is Closed/Voided. So, temporary table is not immutable and permanent table is immutable. But it seems having both temporary table and permanent tables complex the process because records have to move from temp to permanent table, delete records in the temp table.

Will it be better to have just one permanent table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't see an advantage to separating them, especially given that you will probably have a primary key on the Orders table that the OrderItems table will need to reference.  I normally handle this by having a nullable column for "closed" and/or "voided" that is stamped with now() on the appropriate event but left NULL until then.  If you're concerned about having too many open orders, you could have a garbage collection script that runs during off-peak hours to remove them.

Comment: You also aren't saving any resources while increasing complexity, temporary objects still exist on disk, just in the tempDB.  You would also lose any data if the database were to reboot before your application moved the order item to the real table.

Comment: @JonathanFite: Despite the terminology, I suspect OP is considering a table-of-temporaries actually resident in the main database, not a true temporary table in tempdb (or vendor-specific equivalent).

Comment: @JonathanFite  Pieter Geerkens was right about the definition of temp. I didn't mean a temporary objects.

Comment: @jdavidkabr Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention that there was a table called Ticket and it has one-to-many relationships with Orders (a ticket can have many orders). My concern was having a slow performance for a long run. Definitely, inserting must be very fast for all tables: Ticket, Order and OrderItems. What do you mean having a scripts to remove open order? Also, I wonder if there needs to be a history on Ticket/Order for any modifications after it is Closed (just to prevent abusing the system by Managers). I don't have a hard requirement on this... Thanks..

Comment: I said that about removing open orders just because I assumed that the purpose for the temp table was to limit the length of time that an incomplete order stays in the system.  If that's not an issue, then there's no reason to do any garbage collection. For keeping a history, the way I usually do it is have a transaction table that has a foreign key to the order, and just enter into that table what I need for a log of actions done on the order; that's a pretty simple query to pull and display that data on the order details page (or wherever).